# The preview of the custom view I created with Constraint Layout is not visible (Failed to instantiate one or more classes)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-databinding

I created a custom view with Constraint Layout. I used databinding for the management of the elements in the layout. But since I'm using databinding, it doesn't show up in the layout preview. I did not have such a problem with the custom views I made without using databinding. How do i fix this.

I am using databinding like this;

```
  private fun initDataBinding() {
        val inflater = this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.widget_premium_badge, this, true)
    }
```

I am getting an error like

```
Exception Details java.lang.NullPointerException   at com.xxx.app.databinding.WidgetPremiumBadgeBindingImpl.<init>(WidgetPremiumBadgeBindingImpl.java:36)
```

I realized that the problem was because I added variable for databinding. It doesn't appear because the Layout editor cannot handle the variable part. When I removed it, the view in the layout editor improved.
How can I overcome this?

```
  <variable
    name="hasPremium"
    type="Boolean" />
```

Comment: I figured out that having binding variables in your custom view layout causes it to have issues in preview. The route I followed was to not work with binding variables in my custom view layout.

Meaning that whatever you are using this Boolean variable to do in your layout, you just have to do that in your custom view class programmatically. Hope this helps